# Display stars based on what number I get from admin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display stars based on number which I am getting from admin from ACF field, this is the code I have now.

```
<?php if( have_rows('testimonials_reviews_section') ):
            while ( have_rows('testimonials_reviews_section') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="testimonials--reviews-review">
                    <div class="testimonials--review-stars">
                        <span class="star filled">★</span>
                        <span class="star filled">★</span>
                        <span class="star filled">★</span>
                        <span class="star filled">★</span>
                        <span class="star filled">★</span>
                    </div>
                    <?php the_sub_field('stars'); ?>
                    <p class="testimonials--review-text"><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                    <span class="testimonials--review-author"><?php the_sub_field('author'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
```

I have a repeater here, and I will get from sub_field('stars') for example number 3, and what i need is to display all 5 stars but only class "filled" will be there for 3 stars.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You only described what you “need”, but failed to tell us what your actual, specific problem with implementing it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misread the question the first time. You should build the stars dynamically and apply the class if it is less than number of stars.

```
$count = 3; //the_sub_field('stars');
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $class = $i <= $count ? ' filled' : '';
?>
    <span class="star<?php echo $class;?>">★</span>
<?php
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5M3lA

Comment: Hm it works but not completely, this is what I get when I write the_sub_field('stars'). https://ibb.co/coXjuo